# How to setup Elasticsearch with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-rest

I have configured elastic search in a spring application. I am getting this error

```
failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{HDL7B1PCRyGKjqp98KTGZw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

I have not seen any articles or videos online to do something like this. Here are my settings

**application.props**

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
server.port=8086
```

**entity**

```
@Document(indexName = "items", type = "items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private Integer customerId;
    private Integer sku;
    private Integer quantity;
    private String message;
```

**dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Would you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the 9200 port if you try to use rest?

Comment: @XavierBouclet I have tried 9200 but get the same error

Comment: Do you use `elasiticsearch` docker distribution or have you installed it in your machine directly?

Comment: @SachithDickwella I have a docker distribution

Comment: If your' application runs on host machine, did you open respective ports to the host? If you're running the application on another docker container, both containers need to be in same network otherwise.

Comment: @SachithDickwella I can access the docker container with postman and I exposed the ports externally. My application is running in intellij not in docker.